# Jmeter groovy returning a set of ids in Json

Tags: groovy, jmeter

My HTTP Response is like this:

```
  {
  "Result": [
    {
      "xPath": "/BB[001]",
      "name": "Block001",
      "folder": "\\",
      "id": 13,
      "information": [
        {
          "xPath": "/BB[001]",
          "result": "BB1"
        }
      ],
      "error": []
    },
    {
      "xPath": "/TestCases/TestCase[001]",
      "name": "I_TT",
      "folder": "\\Automation-Inbnd\\TT",
      "id": 146,
      "information": [
        {
          "xPath": "/TestCases/TestCase[001]",
          "result": "Test1: TT1"
        },
        {
          "xPath": "/TestCases/TestCase[001]",
          "result": "Folder path: \\Automation-Inbnd\\TT"
        }
      ],
      "error": []
    },
    {
      "xPath": "/TestCases/TestCase[002]",
      "name": "TT",
      "folder": "\\Automation-Inbnd\\TT",
      "id": 147,
      "information": [
        {
          "xPath": "/TestCases/TestCase[002]",
          "result": "Test Case Number 2TTO"
        }
      ],
      "error": []
    }
  ]
}
```

In Groovy JSR223 Post Processor I like to extract only those ids after --> "folder": "\Automation-Inbnd\TT"   so in this case I like to extract only 146, and 147 and NOT 13

A solution for all Ids after

```
  "folder": "\\Automation-Inbnd\\TT",
```

if we can even make TT variable it will be great since I have another test case which uses a different subfolder 
so all ids only after

```
  "folder": "\\Automation-Inbnd\\(*)",
```

where (*)  is anything and then ,

I appreciate your help, since i have spent a lot of time on this. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using JSON extractor String[] Ids = vars.get("id_ALL").split(",");but it gives me all ids even 13

Comment: I also tried --> String result = response.substring(0, response.indexOf('Automation-Inbnd'))  but cant figure out how to get id values after it

Comment: I also tried   def matcher = (response =~ '"folder": "\\\\Automation-Inbnd\\\\TT", id:(\\d+),')

if (matcher.find()) {
 System.out.println('Folder ID = ' + matcher.group(1))
}

Comment: Also --> def matcher = (response =~ 'folder\": \"\\\\Automation-Inbnd\\\\TT", id:(\\d+),')

Answer (score 1):

As alternative solution, you could use **Json Extractor** post-processor, with Jsonpath like this:

```
$..[?(@.folder =~ /\\Automation-Inbnd\\.*?/i)].id
```

Full configuration would look like this:

[image]

This would generate a set of variables `id_1`, `id_2`, e.g. for your sample it would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Thank you @Kiri very elegant solution --> $..[?(@.folder =~ /\\Automation-Inbnd\\.*?/i)].id I love it and it works

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use JsonSlurper:

```
def ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
    .parseText(response)
    .Result
    .findAll { it.folder == '\\Automation-Inbnd\\TT' }
    .id
```

Comment: in JSR223 Post Processor I tried your solution  plus added --> System.out.println('ids ------------- ' + ids)  I am getting   ids ------------- []

Comment: so in my post processor I ahve   def ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
    .parseText(response)
    .Result
    .findAll { it.folder == '\\Automation-Inbnd\\TT' }
    .id

System.out.println('ids ------------- ' + ids)  I dont get anything on ids

Comment: I assume your example JSON in the question is different to that which you are checking

Comment: Thank you @Tim i just didn't understand your solution mainly because I am not that good with groovy. Thanks for helping